# How to interpret the condition inside while? while (+(+k--) !=0)

Tags: c++, operators

We have to tell the output of the following code:

```
int k = 0;
while(+(+k--)!=0){
    k = k++;
}
cout<<k;
```

I am unable to understand what operations are being performed on k inside the while condition, i.e. (+(+k--).

Comment: This condition have not sense for me.

Comment: those unary `+` are useless.

Comment: You can check what the [unary + operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) does from the docs.

Comment: This looks like to be same to ``k--`` after will be a **-1**, if you want instantly, try ``--k``

Comment: Thankyou everyone! I was unable to understand the unary + part.

Answer (score 1):

First understand the concept of unary plus operator (+).

The result of the unary plus operator (+) is the value of its operand. The operand to the unary plus operator must be of an arithmetic type.

Integral promotion is performed on integral operands. The resultant type is the type to which the operand is promoted. Thus, the expression +ch, where ch is of type char, results in type int; the value is unmodified.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/standard-conversions?view=vs-2019

Comment: Just a minor caution: on the most common platforms, unary plus on a `char` does, as you say, produce an `int`. But there are hardware architectures where a `char` and an `int` are the same size, and then you hit the value-preservation rules; a `char` could be unsigned, and then the unary plus produces an `unsigned int`, because an `int` can't represent all the possible values of an unsigned `char`.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is a NoOp. The compiler will optimize it away and assign -1 to k;

The unary + makes no sense here.

godbolt input:

```
int main()
{
    int k = 0;
    while(+(+k--)!=0){
        k = k++;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Output is:

```
   mov     eax, -1
   ret
```

Comment: Not quite. The behavior of the code is undefined. `k = k++` is nonsense. You're right about the unary plus.